# Cartesian product of two countable sets is countable - without a function $f(m,n)=2^m⋅3^n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that this question has been asked (and answered) before, using a pairing function

$f(m,n) = 2^m \cdot 3^n$, or another similar function $f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y−2)(x+y−1)}{2}$.

However, I have trouble coming up with such a function on my own (more so if I need to prove i.e. that a Cartesian product of *three* countable sets is countable). Here's what I have come up with.

**My attempt**:

Let $A=\{a_1, a_2, a_3...\}$ and $B=\{b_1, b_2, b_3...\}$. The elements of the Cartesian product are $A \times B = \{ (a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2), (a_1, b_3)...$

Now, if we arrange the elements of the cartesian product by the sum of indices $i$ and $j$ in $(a_i, b_j)$:

$(a_1, b_1)$

$(a_1, b_2), (a_2, b_1)$

$(a_1, b_3), (a_2, b_2), (a_3, b_1)$

$(a_1, b_4), (a_2, b_3), (a_3, b_2), (a_4, b_1)$

Each group contains the same sum of indices, and each group is sorted where $i$ is eventually increasing and $j$ is eventually decreasing. Now, we just assign natural numbers since this list of $(a_i, b_j$) is sorted. By doing this, I think we have ensured a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Once you know the product of two countable sets is countable, you can easily prove by induction that the product of finitely many countable sets is countable.

Comment: Tangential, but if you’d like an injective function from $\mathbb N^m$ to $\mathbb N$, if you let $p_1, \dots, p_m$ be distinct primes then $f(i_1, \dots, i_m) = p_1^{i_1} \cdots p_m^{i_m}$ is injective.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks! Just for the sake of completeness, do you think what I tried to do is correct in proving?

Comment: @kipf Thank you! Will come in handy.

Comment: Your method of counting is fine. It is associated with the invertible pairing function $$f:\Bbb Z_+^2\to\Bbb Z_+:(i,j)\mapsto\tfrac12(i+j-2)(i+j-1)+i.$$